# Call WPF Application during windows 7 shutdown progress

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, c#

I wanna call a WPF application, that during the windows 7 shutdown progress, will copy some files from computer to the server. The WPF application will show the copy files progress with progress bar.

How can i call wpf application during shutdown phase? I have see on my computer many times, when i logoff or shutdown, windows will start synchronizing program, to synchronize profile data with server. How can i do exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7136573/614863

Subscribe to the [`Application.SessionEnding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.sessionending.aspx) event.